# Replace dataframe values via n lists

Tags: python, pandas

Couldn't really find sth appropriate here in stackoverflow - I want to classify data in a dataframe column via *n* lists. An example for the df would be:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | blue |
| 521 | blue |
| 77 | green |
| 7211 | red |
| 15 | cold |
| 612 | hot |
| 820 | hot |
| 142 | medium |

The goal would be to define a list with unique colors (red, blue, green) and replace values in the column ‘Description’ that are included in the list ‘Colors’ with the string 'Colors'.

```
df['Classification'] = df['Description'].replace(to_replace=[colors], value=["Colors"])
```

So far so good, but how can I also replace values according to *n* lists? That sounds like it should be trivial, but I have been struggling to do this (in a somewhat elegant manner).

Taking the dummy data from the example sth like this (which doesn't work) would be the goal:

```
df['Classification'] = df['Description'].replace(to_replace=[colors, temperature], value=["Colors", "Temperature"])
```

Still rather new to programming & python, any help/ pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `colors`?

Comment: colors, colours, .. w/e your heart is longing for. In the rare chance you were serious: its a dummy list whose elements should be replaced with the list name

Comment: Haha, sorry, I wasn't being very clear, but that rare chance is the reality. I thought maybe you forget to post the contents of `colors`, but I didn't read the whole post.

Comment: (I use American english, so colors is the one for me lol :)

Comment: Ahaha, okay. But yeh, I should have specified the list in the code block too, not only via text. Next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick scan of the [replace method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) lets me believe that the use of multiple lists is not supported.

However, you could easily build a dictionary mapping all your `Description` values to a `Classification` and use the `replace` or `map` Series method:

```py
# Define the dictionary
mapping = {
    'blue': 'color',
    'red': 'color',
    'green': 'color',
    'hot': 'temperature',
    'cold': 'temperature',
}

# apply the mapping   
df['Classification'] = df['Description'].map(mapping)
```

**EDIT**: added how to build the dictionary

Here is how I would do it:

```py
# setting up the lists
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
temperature = ['hot', 'medium', 'cold']

# mapping list values to category names
name_mapping = {
    'Colors': colors,
    'Temperature': temperature
    # can be extended with other lists
}

mapping = dict()
for classification, value_list in name_mapping.items():
    for value in value_list:
        mapping[value] = classification
```

And you can then use the `mapping` dictionary as stated in the original answer.

Comment: that works, but seems a bit clunky. Is there no cleaner way to solve this? Still accepting your answer as a solution as it technically is one. And thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, so I don't pretend to hold the truth, but I think that what you are trying to achieve is "map" values ('red', 'hot', ...) to categories ('color', 'temperature', ...). Using a dictionary is to me the "pythonic" way of representing this mapping, and the 'map' method the "pandistic" way of achieving the transformation. I will edit my answer to show how to build this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Pierre Massé answer: I agree that creating a mapping with a dict is and applying `.replace(mapping_dict)` is a nice way to go about it. I think the final solution can a a bit cleaner though.

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
temperatures = ['hot', 'medium', 'cold']

# create a mapping dict per list
cd = {col: "Color" for col in colors}
td = {temp: "Temperature" for temp in temperatures}

# merge the dicts
mapping_dict = {**cd, **td}

# apply mapping
df['Classification'] = df['Description'].replace(mapping_dict)
```